# Knockout binding parent and child node

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am having issue of returning the child node, seems like it does not want to bind.

Here is the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gnpoe6a6/2/

```
var viewModel = {
model: ko.mapping.fromJS(data),
people: ko.mapping.fromJS([]),
loadInitialData: function() {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, dataMappingOptions, viewModel.people);        
}   
};
```

Comment: It's a little unclear, what you are trying to do, and what's going wrong. The fromJS method only takes two arguments - the json-data, and the viewmodel. The documentation says nothing about an options argument. Try removing that.

Comment: Apologize about that, I've updated the jsFiddle. I want to display the model.name and the child ID and child name.

Comment: The root of the issue is that your data object is within an array and you are not handling it as such. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gnpoe6a6/4/) to illustrate the returned structure of the `ko.mapping` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing something like this .

**View Model :**

```
    var viewModel = function(data){
    this.name =ko.observable();
    this.array=ko.observableArray();
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping,this);
    this.loadInitialData=function(){
    this.array(ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping,this).TM1ChoreProcessRel());
        console.log(this.array());
    }.bind(this);
};

var data = {//you json Data};

var Person = function(data) {
    this.ID = ko.observable();
    this.Name = ko.observable();
    this.ParemeterValues = ko.observable();
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, this)
};

var mapping = {
    create:function(options){
        return  new Person(options.data);
    },
     'TM1ChoreProcessRel': {
         create: function(options) {
             return ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);         
     }
}
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(data));
```

Wokring fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/5cfa3/95/)**

Comment: Hi, this is almost what I needed, but when I tried to implement, looks like the TM1.ChoreProcessRel is changed to TM1ChoreProcessRel
This has been an issue as well for me. 

I've tried changing the 
this.array(ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping,this).TM1ChoreProcessRel()); to use the TM1.ChoreProcessRel but no luck.

Comment: i believe that can be a serious question how to access observable value if its name is separated by 'dot' . ex: `TM1.ChoreProcessRel` . please feel free to make a new post (even i am keen to know)